# Woocommerce Check if Guest Customer

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I'm using WooCommerce and have trouble in checking if the order is a guest customer. 
Tried using `$order  = new WC_Order($orderid);` found nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the best way to do this (at least as of WC 3.3.3) is to use [WC_Order->get_user()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#437-444): "Get the user associated with the order. False for guests."

It will return a WP_User for logged in customers, or `false` for guest checkout.

Note that if you need to reliably determine the actual checkout method used, you should *not* rely on WordPress's `get_user_by()` function; this will tell you whether a user account *exists* matching the email on the order, but not whether it was actually used to place the order. Someone who has an account can still order as a guest if they don't login; whether this distinction is important may depend on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get billing email and check if user is registered:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$user = get_user_by('email', $order->billing_email);

if(isset($user->ID)){
    //Registered
}else{
    //Guest
}
```

Comment: Depending on what you are doing with this information this is a security flaw. A random user could use the same email as a registered user and they will fall into this case.  WC_Order->get_user() seems to be the best one for that